# Can I replace just the top rotten half of a wall stud rather than the whole thing?

Tags: walls, framing

The reason is I cannot readily access the sill plate. There is fireplace brickwork in front of the drywall there. I guess the best thing is add a sister that rests atop the sill plate but is not attached to it, and is attached to and reinforces the old and new stud halves. This is a load-bearing exterior wall. (The top plate needs replacing also but that's another subject.)

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a photo?

Comment: As long as the bottom half is good and you nail/screw the sister to the bottom half, it will work.

Comment: Photo added for illustration

Comment: Technically the studs also must resist horizontal loads from wind. The bad studs look good down low, so I would just take care to fasten the lap with 3-16d nails at the topmost good spot. I would also go 2 ft down from there to install another 3-16d nails. Just guessing on the 3-16d being good enough. As the 2ft increases, the strength increases.

Comment: Looking at your picture, it _looks_ bad, but I'd bet most of the wood in those studs is still there.  If so, almost anything you add would make it sturdier than the original.  Can you scrape off the rotted surfaces of the studs, to see how much is left?  The hardest part about just sistering in new studs there is the wiring you would have to work around.  Maybe you can add studs rotated 90 degrees, so they don't interfere with the wiring.  That would give the same vertical capacity.

Comment: @BaddDadd How much is the maximum amount of rotted wood I should be able to scrape away? I've scraped off abut half an inch in some places and that seems like a lot. Even so, I will add sister studs so maybe I don't need to remove the old ones at all. I've moved the wiring out of the way to put back later, that's not an issue.

Comment: @BaddDadd, rotating the studs 90 degrees is only okay in non-bearing walls. There are two buckling strengths associated with a 2x4. By orienting the stud like normal, the stud gets braced by the wall sheathing to prevent the weaker buckling mode from occurring. Rotating a stud by 90 degrees, it's strength goes down to the weak buckling mode's value. The studs are also bending members that transfer wind load to the top and bottom plates, so orienting them the weak way impacts that strength too.

Comment: I daresay your biggest problem will be dealing with the cable.

Comment: @Huesmann That's good because I've already pulled all electrical wiring out of the way and can easily put it back.